# Pyenv - virtualenv how to specify virtualenv used by using .file?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyenv

How to specify pyenv-virtual env using .file so that when I cd to a directory I automatically get correct pyenv and correct virtualenv selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pyenv envaroment can be managed using `.python-version` files.

First, install required python version using the command below example. You can find list of all available python versions with `pyenv install --list` in your terminal.

```
Pyenv install 3.5.2
```

Next create pyenv virtual environment using following command. my-virtual-env-3.5.2 is the name of your environment

```
pyenv virtualenv 3.5.2 my-virtual-env-3.5.2
```

Next go to directory where you want to use this virtualenv and create `.python-version` file

Edit your envaroment name and path to this file.

```
3.5.2/envs/my-virtual-env-3.5.2
```

In case you are not sure about the path and name of your environment you can list your environments running >

`pyenv versions`

In your terminal